# Where download php_memcache.dll?

Tags: php, memcached

I'm trying to download from http://pecl4win.php.net/ext.php/php_memcache.dll but "The pecl4win build box is temporarily out of service. We're preparing a new build system."

Thank you.

PHP version is 5.3

Comment: Hmm dunno if this is the right place for this kind of question. Anyways have you tried this page: http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/PlatformWindows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some extensions, compiled for windows, can be found here : **http://downloads.php.net/pierre/**

There are several versions of `php_memcache.dll` ; the *right one* will depend on your version of PHP.

See the left column of http://windows.php.net/ for more informations about that.

*Note : this is temporary, until extensions are available on windows.php.net -- but that "temporary" has been quite long already...*

Answer (score 3):

can be found here http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/
my english is so poor,cant`t say more,Forgive me.

Comment: I was able to run memcache thanks to this link with PHP 5.2